# Storing App Store Connect API key securely for fastlane?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane

I have a GitHub action that runs `fastlane` to build and deploy releases to TestFlight in a CI pipeline. I use an App Store Connect API Key to authenticate non-interactively.

[Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api) explicitly say:

> Important
>
> Keep your API keys secure and private. You should never share your keys, **store keys in a code repository**, or include keys in client-side code.

but every example I see just passes the `.p8` file to the `app_store_connect_api_key()` command either as plain-text file checked into source control (via the `key_filepath` argument):

```
lane :release do
  app_store_connect_api_key(
    key_id: "D383SF739",
    issuer_id: "6053b7fe-68a8-4acb-89be-165aa6465141",
    key_filepath: "./AuthKey_D383SF739.p8"
  )

  pilot
end
```

or as the plaintext key itself (via the `key` argument):

```
lane :release do
  app_store_connect_api_key(
    key_id: "D383SF739",
    issuer_id: "6053b7fe-68a8-4acb-89be-165aa6465141",
    "key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHknlhdlYdLu\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
  )

  pilot
end
```

**Is there a more secure way to store it and still use it in a CI pipeline?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the values you want to keep private as environment variables. As far as I know, all CI/CD services allow setting environment variables. You can use `ENV['XYZ']` to access any environment variable in your Fastfile.

See more information: https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/github/

Comment: This was dead simple, and exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize that the `Fastfile` could access GitHub repository secrets.